# bash receive udp packets tcpdump

Tags: bash, udp, tcpdump, netcat

On one server, I am receiving udp packets on 192.168.0.51 from an application running on 192.168.0.21, and have to reply with a specific acknowledgement packet.

The solution I wrote works as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
send_ack() {
<calculate $ack - code removed>
echo -n "$ack" | nc -u -w1 192.168.0.21 8076
}
while [ 1 ]
do
    for string in $(/usr/sbin/tcpdump -Avnni eth0 -c 1 dst 192.168.0.51 and udp port 8076)
    do
        send_ack &
    done
done
```

The issue is that I seem to have some running condition when packets arrive too quickly, I guess they arrive before tcpdump restarts.
I tried -l for single line buffer instead of -c 1 to no success.

Would anyone have any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Thanks, looking forward :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your program is that packets will slip by in between tcpdump invocations, since you're just running it to capture a single packet using `-c 1` and then exiting again each time.

The solution would be to run tcpdump continuously in line buffered mode (`-l`) with its output piped to a process reading that.

```
#!/bin/bash
# tcpdump line buffered and piped to infinite loop
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -Avnni eth0 -l dst 192.168.0.51 and udp port 8076 | \
  while true; do
    # read output line by line
    read result
    # only act on non-blank output
    if [ "$result" != "" ]; then
      echo "Read a packet: $result"
      # perform whatever action
      send_ack &
    fi
  done
```

In addition to this you may also want to experiment with the `-B` option to `tcpdump` which lets you set the buffer size, and with different options for `read`.